Player in GODOT 4 spawns with weapon already visible
Every time the player spawns in the starting position, the weapon is in hand. Only when I press my attack does the weapon disappear.
I'm still new to Godot, so I need help understanding the logic here. Is this an issue with my animation?
My weapon.gd script
extends Node2D

var weapon: Area2D

func _ready():
    if get_children().is_empty(): return
    
    weapon = get_children()[0]
func enable():
    if !weapon: return
    
    visible = true
    weapon.enable()
    
func disable():
    if !weapon: return
    
    visible = false
    weapon.disable

My player.gd script
extends CharacterBody2D

signal healthChanged

@export var speed: int = 35
@onready var animations = $AnimationPlayer
@onready var effects = $Effects
@onready var hurtBox = $hurtBox
@onready var hurtTimer = $hurtTimer
@onready var weapon = $weapon
@onready var death = $death

@export var maxHealth = 3
@onready var currentHealth: int = maxHealth

@export var knockbackPower: int = 500

# Assuming Inventory is another class
@export var inventory: Inventory

var lastAnimDirection: String = "Down"
var isHurt: bool = false
var isAttacking: bool = false

func _ready():
    effects.play("RESET")

func handleInput():
    var moveDirection = Input.get_vector("ui_left", "ui_right", "ui_up", "ui_down")
    velocity = moveDirection * speed
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("attack"):
        attack()

func attack():
    animations.play("attack" + lastAnimDirection)
    isAttacking = true
    weapon.enable()
    await animations.animation_finished
    weapon.disable()
    isAttacking = false

func updateAnimation():
    if isAttacking: return
    
    if velocity.length() == 0:
        if animations.is_playing():
            animations.stop()
    else:    
        var direction = "Down"
        if velocity.x < 0: direction = "Left"
        elif velocity.x > 0: direction = "Right"
        elif velocity.y < 0: direction = "Up"
        
        animations.play("walk" + direction)
        lastAnimDirection = direction

func handleCollision():
    for i in get_slide_collision_count():
        var collision = get_slide_collision(i)
        var collider = collision.get_collider()
        print_debug(collider.name)

func _physics_process(delta):
    handleInput()
    move_and_slide()
    handleCollision()
    updateAnimation()
    
    if !isHurt:
        for area in hurtBox.get_overlapping_areas():
            if area.name == "hitBox":
                hurtByEnemy(area)

func hurtByEnemy(area):
    currentHealth -= 1
    if currentHealth <= 0:
        die()  # Call the die function 
        
    healthChanged.emit(currentHealth)
    isHurt = true
    
    knockback(area.get_parent().velocity)
    effects.play("hurtBlink")
    hurtTimer.start()
    await hurtTimer.timeout
    effects.play("RESET")
    isHurt = false

func die():
    # Reset character state upon death
    currentHealth = maxHealth
    # Additional reset logic 
    healthChanged.emit(currentHealth)

    position = Vector2(0, 0)
    velocity = Vector2.ZERO
    
    # Play death animation or effects if desired
    animations.play("death")
    effects.play("deathEffect")
    
func _on_hurt_box_area_entered(area):
    if area.has_method("collect"):
        area.collect(inventory)

func knockback(enemyVelocity: Vector2):
    var knockbackDirection = (enemyVelocity - velocity).normalized() * knockbackPower
    velocity = knockbackDirection
    move_and_slide()

func _on_hurt_box_area_exited(area): pass


I was expecting the player to start with hands empty.

Without seeing any of your other code, try initializing visible as false in ready(). ready is called once when the scene is spawned, so this should have it start off as non-visible. So func _ready(): \n visible = false \n if get_children().is_empty(): return \n weapon = get_children()[0]

What can be happening is that you're importing your weapon in your player script by reference from the node tree, by default this weapon node has the weapon sprite visible.
In your attack function you do weapon.enable() and then weapon.disable(), which explains why it works after you attack the first time.
to potentially solve this you can add weapon.disable() in the _ready() function of your weapon script.
so it would look like this:
 func _ready():
    if get_children().is_empty(): return
    
    weapon = get_children()[0]
    weapon.disable();

